# .pbxproj merge conflicts without git marks

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, pbxproj

I just pulled from remote repo to my local repo and .pbxproj merge conflict happens. However when I opened it I didn't find any git marks( which means <<< === >>> ) so I don't know how to resolve this conflict. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried `git mergetool`? Also see [Fix merge conflicts in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/fix-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Comment: Brilliant. I've resolved it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am writing this answer on behalf of @Caesar.
Refer this - [Fix merge conflicts in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)